# Can't retrieve data after storing to disk using NSKeyedArchiver

Tags: objective-c

I'm storing a custom object in a dictionary which i'm then saving to disk using NSKeyedArchiver.  In the same method where I save the data, I do a quick test at the end to make sure I can load the data but everything comes out  null.  Why is this happening?  I've been following the instructions in this tutorial: http://cocoadevcentral.com/articles/000084.php

```
/** Interface of viewcontroller**/

#import "User.h"

@interface BWViewController : UIViewController
{
    IBOutlet UITextField *userNameField;
    IBOutlet UITextField *passwordField;
    IBOutlet UILabel * loginStatus;
}

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *holdPassword, *holdUserName;

    -(IBAction)signUpButton;
    -(IBAction)loginButton;
    -(NSString*) pathForDataFile;
    -(void) saveDataToDisk:(User*) someUser;
    -(User *) loadDataFromDisk:(NSString*) theKey;

@end

 /**Implementation file **/

#import "BWViewController.h"

@interface BWViewController ()

@end

@implementation BWViewController

@synthesize holdPassword,holdUserName;

-(IBAction)signUpButton
{

    User * firstUser = [[User alloc] init];
    firstUser.userName = userNameField.text;
    firstUser.password = passwordField.text;

    /**To save to file**/
    [self saveDataToDisk:firstUser];

    loginStatus.text = @"Thanks for signing up";

}

-(NSString*) pathForDataFile
{

    NSFileManager * fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSString *folder =@"~/Library/Application Support/signUpApp/";
    folder = [folder stringByExpandingTildeInPath];

    if([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:folder] == NO)
    {
        [fileManager createFileAtPath:folder contents:nil attributes:nil];
    }

    NSString *fileName = @"signUpApp.demo";
    return [folder stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];

}

-(void) saveDataToDisk:(User*) someUser
{

    User * savingUser = someUser;
    NSString * path = [self pathForDataFile];
    NSMutableDictionary * rootObject = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    [rootObject setValue:savingUser forKey:userNameField.text];
    [NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject:rootObject toFile:path];
    NSLog(@"saving user to disk %@", savingUser.userName);

    /**Testing the load process**/
    User * testLoadUser;    
    NSMutableDictionary *unRootObject;
    unRootObject = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:path];
    testLoadUser = [unRootObject valueForKey:userNameField.text];
    NSLog(@"Testing the unarchive %@ and %@", testLoadUser.userName, testLoadUser.password);

}

/**User implementation file**/

#import "User.h"

@implementation User

@synthesize userName, password;

- (void) encodeWithCoder: (NSCoder *)coder
{
    [coder encodeObject: userName forKey:@"username"];
    [coder encodeObject: password forKey:@"password"];
}

- (id) initWithCoder: (NSCoder *)coder
{
    if (self = [super init])
    {
        self.userName = [coder decodeObjectForKey:@"username"];
        self.password = [coder decodeObjectForKey:@"password"];
    }
    return self;
 }

@end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like iOS code, but you're using a Mac OS X convention for determining the folder for the path. In iOS, you should use the Documents folder.

For iOS, the path for the filename in the Documents folder should be:

```
- (NSString*) pathForDataFile
{
    NSString *documentsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)[0];
    NSString *path          = [documentsPath stringByAppendingString:@"signUpApp.demo"];

    return path;
}
```

I'd also suggest checking the return code from `archiveRootObject` method, to confirm whether the archive succeeded or not. No point in going further if that failed.

Also, in your old `pathForDataFile`, you're calling `createFileAtPath:contents:attributes:`, but I suspect you intended `createDirectoryAtURL:withIntermediateDirectories:attributes:error:`. The former is for creating a file, and the latter is for creating a folder. And your code is trying to create a folder.

Comment: Just changed out the code and your code worked.  So my method for determining the pathway to the folder was for Mac OS?  What exactly is happenign here: `NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)[0];`

Comment: @Brosef That line retrieves the app's "Documents" folder path. For information about the "Documents" folder, see [About the iOS File System](https://developer.apple.com/library/Mac/DOCUMENTATION/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010672-CH2-SW12). That function returns an array, so we're just grabbing the first (and only) item in that array.

Answer (score 0):

Quick things you can check..

1) IS file is Actually created on the location ?

2) Is there any data (random chars) in that file ?

3) Is your code contains `<NSCopying>` protocol in your user.h class?

4) Make sure you don't have `- (id) initWithCoder: (NSCoder *)coder` and `- (void) encodeWithCoder: (NSCoder *)coder` in your header file.

Comment: I was using NSUserDefaults instead yesterday and there is a plist for the saved data.  But since switching over to the new saving method I don't see any new plists.